# Disable animation under conditions in React Native

Tags: react-native, animation

I made a screen (I call it "S1") with a view that translate from the right to the left. That works fine. As this view is used in the same place on different screens to navigate between screens, I'd like to disable the animation each time this view need to be recreated on other screens or S1.

I pass the parameter needToAnimate on each screen and the value is always good.

I've already tried different solutions:
- I encapsulate my view either in a  or , according to needToAnimate but only the  is created, and I can't understand why.
- I also try to change the value of the beginning marginLeft, always according to needToAnimate, but the value is always the same.

So can you help me?

Here my code

```
  animatedMarginLeft = this.needToAnimate
? new Animated.Value(screenWidth() - 240)
: new Animated.Value(17);

componentDidMount() {
Animated.timing(this.animatedMarginLeft, {
  toValue: 17,
  duration: 300,
  easing: Easing.linear
}).start();
}

public render() {
console.log(this.needToAnimate);
const leftMenu = this.getleftMenu();

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        styles.animation_view,
        { marginLeft: this.animatedMarginLeft }
      ]}
    >
      <MyObject/>
    </Animated.View>
```

....

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The problem came from the variable needToAnimate which was determined by a navigation parameter

```
  needToAnimate = this.props.navigation.getParam("animate", true);
```

But this was not considered as a boolean but as a String. So a log of needToAnimate can display false but the condition if (this.needToAnimate) was always true.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to animate under a certain condition only?

If that's the case you should have a condition in componentDidMount just like this:

```
componentDidMount(){

    if(needToAnimate){

        Animated.timing(this.animatedMarginLeft, {
            toValue: 17,
            duration: 300,
            easing: Easing.linear
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did it, but it did not work, the view remains to the right side (animatedMarginLeft =  new Animated.Value(screenWidth() - 240))